# Java Class Requirements

Tags: java, class

In the following problem,

> **1.  Which of the following is true regarding Java classes?** 
>
>   **a)**    All classes must have 1 parent but may have any number of children (derived or extended) classes. 
> **b)**    All classes must have 1 child (derived or extended) class but may have any number of parent classes.
>   
> **c)**  All classes must have 1 parent class and may have a single child (derived or extended) class.
>   **d)**  All classes can have any number (0 or more) of parent classes and any number of children (derived or extended) classes.
>   
> **e)**  All classes can have either 0 or 1 parent class and any number of children (derived or extended) classes.

I believed the answer would be **e)**. I thought this because all classes can have at most 1 parent class or at least 0 (the Object class has no parent class). Furthermore, you can have any number of children (assuming integers greater than or equal to 0). The correct answer was **a)**:

> All classes must have 1 parent but may have any number of children (derived or extended) classes.

Does this mean that you can't consider the Object class to be a class?

Does the Object class have a parent?

Also, I recently asked another question on Java, also from this series of assignments (actually an optional test-review, not homework). Sorry for the two posts, but I didn't think it followed correct etiqutte to combine the questions into one post.

Comment: Because in Java every class has a base parent class (*Object*).

Comment: @SpencerWieczorek what about the Object class? It doesn't have a base parent class.

Comment: Oh boy, you need to ask the professor; `final class B` can not have "any number of children" so there is an exception to answer `e`.

Comment: @elliotfrisch zero is any number, so that's not an issue. The issue is the number of parents of Object.

Comment: @ElliottFrisch just read up on final classes and their uses. Really interesting. Thanks for the extra info, but wow. This question is really bad.

Comment: @MadPhysicist You say zero, I say three. `B` can't have three. Perhaps that was the instructor's intent - but I wouldn't want to commit to it myself.

Comment: @elliotfrisch. I see your point. Sounds like the professor needs a refresher course indeed.

Comment: @EricWiener Sorry didn't read your whole post. I see your point, although your instructor is probably implicitly excluding `Object` (*but still I'd say your technically correct in this case*). Similarly when the Java Doc's state *"Every class has Object as a superclass"*. But yes `Object` doesn't have a base class since it's the super class of Java.

Answer (score 1):

Technically speaking, neither A nor E is correct. The `Object` class is unique in having no parent; every other class must have exactly one parent. Thus, it is neither true that every class **must have** a parent -- `Object` does not -- nor is it true that all classes **can have** zero parents -- only `Object` is allowed do that.

However, if we restrict the question to user-defined classes -- leaving the special case of `Object` out of the picture -- answer A is correct.

Comment: @SocraticPhoenix so what ..if final class exists? Update: OK I got it.. concern for final class is valid as per question context

Answer (score 0):

The question seems to be a bit misleading. (e) seems to be the closest to the correct.
The following concepts can help in understanding the question better:

- Object class is the superclass of all the Java classes.
- Java does not support multiple inheritance
- Multiple Inheritance can be achieved in Java using interfaces.
- Interfaces are not classes
- A class which is not final can be subclassed by any number of Java classes